# How to use AMFPHP with Apache Royale

Tags: visual-studio-code, amfphp, apache-royale

I have an issue on using `SimpleRemoteObject`. (sdk 0.9.6)

My actual website is using this code to call remote function with Amfphp :

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="ro" source="aadmin" destination="amfphp">
    <mx:method name="siteLogin" fault="{onRcv_siteLoginErr(event)}" result="{onRcv_siteLogin(event)}"/>
</mx:RemoteObject>
```

As `<mx:method/>` does't exist in Apache Royale I set this code :

```
 </js:beads>
        <js:SimpleRemoteObject id="sro" source="aadmin" result="onResult(event)" fault="onFault(event)"
                         endPoint = "http://amfphp.myserver_url.com/gateway.php"
                         destination = "amfphp" />
 </js:beads>
```

`aadmin` is my php class service name

To call my function I do :

```
 sro.send("siteLogin",["123"]);
```

where `siteLogin` is my function to call inside `aadmin` class

Running this, I have this issue :

```
The class {Amf3Broker} could not be found under the class path {/home/www/amfphp/services/amfphp/Amf3Broker.php}
```

Why does it show `Amf3Broker` ? Does anyone have an exemple of working `SimpleRemoteObject` with `amfphp` ?

Server side I use https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-1.9

Do I need to setup a `service-config.xml` file ? If yes how to use it with compiler ? (I tried "services": "services-config.xml" in compilerOptions but not working)

Here is my service-config.xml :

```
<services-config>
    <services>
        <service id="amfphp-flashremoting-service" class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService" messageTypes="flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage">
            <destination id="amfphp">
                <channels>
                    <channel ref="my-amfphp"/>
                </channels>
                <properties>
                    <source>*</source>
                </properties>
            </destination>
        </service>
    </services>
<channels>
    <channel-definition id="my-amfphp" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint uri="http://amfphp.myserver.com/gateway.php" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties><add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers></properties>
    </channel-definition>
</channels> 
</services-config>
```

**Now I have do a test with `amfphp V2.0` from https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0**

This is a little better, but I have an error. It seem that there is an issue with `_explicitType` property. Moreover I don't see my argument ('123') in [requestMessage]

```
    /onStatusî$flex.messaging.messages.ErrorMessage
correlationId   faultCode@ faultDetailfaultStringvUndefined property: stdClass::$_explicitType . 
<br>file:  /home/www/mysite.com/amfphpv2/Plugins/AmfphpFlexMessaging/AmfphpFlexMessaging.php 
<br>line: 113 
<br>context: Array
(
    [requestMessage] => Amfphp_Core_Amf_Message Object
        (
            [targetUri] => null
            [responseUri] => /1
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [body] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                            [clientId] => 
                            [correlationId] => 
                            [destination] => amfphp
                            [headers] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                            [messageId] => EF4BF9E3-5C02-1060-1FF3-5D9781F55A31
                            [operation] => 13
                            [timeToLive] => 0
                            [timestamp] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [serviceRouter] => Amfphp_Core_Common_ServiceRouter Object
        (
            [serviceFolders] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /home/www/mysite.com/amfphpv2/Core/../Services/
                )

            [serviceNames2ClassFindInfo] => Array
                (
                    [AmfphpMonitorService] => Amfphp_Core_Common_ClassFindInfo Object
                        (
                            [absolutePath] => /home/www/mysite.com/amfphpv2/Plugins/AmfphpMonitor/AmfphpMonitorService.php
                            [className] => AmfphpMonitorService
                        )

                    [AmfphpDiscoveryService] => Amfphp_Core_Common_ClassFindInfo Object
                        (
                            [absolutePath] => /home/www/mysite.com/amfphpv2/Plugins/AmfphpDiscovery/AmfphpDiscoveryService.php
                            [className] => AmfphpDiscoveryService
                        )

                )

            [checkArgumentCount] => 1
        )

    [explicitTypeField] => _explicitType
)
    rootCause
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some tested working code on 0.9.6 sdk (please notice that you must use `config flex` to be able to use mx if you have mx library issue). tested with v1.9 and v2.0 AMFPHP from silexlabs :

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:RemoteObject id="ro"  result="onResult(event)" fault="onFault(event)" source="your-service-php-class"
                        endpoint = "https://www.your-amfphp-server.com/amfphp/gateway.php"
                        destination = "amfphp" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

Then in script

```
ro.getOperation("your-php-function-to-call").send("your-param");
```

[update]
**Important** : be sure to have this in your application else you will have error like `*The class {Amf3Broker} could not be found*`

```
<mx:beads>
    <js:ClassAliasBead />
</mx:beads>
```

[update#2]
You what to use `config royale` but also wants MX libs to use MX remote object ? Here is how :
https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/issues/495#issuecomment-539906300

Answer (score 1):

the backends I know are working (from my own experience) are **Java** and **.NET(Fluorine)**. **AMFPHP** must work too. Others tried it but was almost a year ago when AMF was not completely developed. Right now AMF in Royale is very robust and works very good with all types with the exception of Vector and Dictionary (I suppose those will come some day but since are AS3 types, has lower priority for now).

The main thing here is to use `MXRoyale` version of `RemoteObject` (`mx:RemoteObject` emulation) since this one is the most closest to Flex RemoteObject. The others in `Network` lib are more lighter classes implemented as beads that were the first ones to come to Royale. But at least in my case I switched to `mx:RemoteObject`, so I can ensure the others are working at the same level.